# How long it would take if I withdraw bitcoin to my bitcoin address through mtgox?

Tags: mtgox, withdrawal

I want to get bitcoin ,not Dollars.
A friend of mine wants to travel to China next month.The prize of bitcoin in China is higher than America.So he think it is good way to change Dollars into RMB.
So I come up with this question.

Comment: Why not start withdrawing immediately (if you haven't already)? The sooner you start the sooner you'll do it.